# passing props form child to parent component in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, components, state

```
return
 <div>
    <RadioOptions />
    <GenButton />
    <OutputPass />
 </div>
```

I recently worked on my side-project and I found an issue in my code. inRadiooptions  I used some useState hooks, and I want to pass that state from Radiooptions component to its parent(passGen) and then from there, pass that state toGet Button component to check some condition and if nothings wrong, generate the password. (I'll also attach my GitHub repo for better access to my source code)

https://github.com/arviinmo/palora/tree/main/components/passwordgenerator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't pass props from child to parent in React, it's only one way (from parent to child).

You should either:

- Put the state in the parent component and manipulate it from the child component by passing the setter function in the props
- Use something like Redux Toolkit to create a global state that all components can have access to

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you show me how to do that?

Comment: Basically go to passGen component, declare the useState that you need there instead of declaring it in RadioOptions. Then pass the state to RadioOptions like this: <RadioOptions state={state} setState={setState} /> then use those accordingly inside RadioOptions to change the values of the state. To do that you should add the keyword props: function RadioOptions(props), then you can access state and setState by doing props.state and props.setState

Comment: i updated the project but it still don't work. could you probably check it and tell my why it don't work?

Comment: You should put the onChange event on the checkbox input and not on the labels

Answer (score 3):

For the newcomers here do it so:

Parent component:

```
import Child from './Child';
export default function Parent() {
        const data_from_child = (data) => {
        console.log(data); // or set the data to a state
    }

    return (
        <Child setter={data_from_child} /> //pass the function to the child
    )
}
```

Child component:

```
export default function Child ({setter}) {
    setter('Data from Child');
    return (<></>)
}
```