# react child not re rendering after change in parent

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react, and I need to re render a child component once is updated in the parent.
I read here that in react you can not pass data from the child back to the parent,
so I added an update function to the props.

The thing is when I update the object in the parent, the child does not see the changes.

Any ideas on what Im missing?

[here is the repo I'm working on (file Game.js)](https://github.com/pato5320/braillesson/blob/main/src/game/Game.js#L14)

This is the question suggesting to pass an update function

[passing props form child to parent component in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913781/passing-props-form-child-to-parent-component-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

React is using props and [state](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) to handle data.
You are using props mostly right, but you are not working with state.
State is holding data inside component like variable, but has one big advantage, if changed component will rerender.

So your whole mistake you made is that you are using variable and not state.

Your code:

```js
    let letter_model = {
        char : letters[letter],
        update : function(update){
            this.char[update] = this.char[update] ? 0 : 1
            console.log('model ' + this.char)
        }
    }
```

should may be like this

```js
    // don't forget to import useState from react library
    // initialize state with default value
    const [char, update] = useState({ letters[letter] });
    // update states value (this will trigger rerender)
    // update("newValue")
```